# Liferay 7 DXP EE Form Email Formatting

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I've created a new custom form in Liferay DXP EE. I would also like to modify and create a custom formatting for how the email is sent. The current email displays the for label then has a line break and then shows the enter value below it like so:

```
•   Form Label 1
Form value 1
•   Form Label 2
Form value 2
```

I would like it to display as follows:

```
•   Form Label 1: Form value 1    • Form Label 2: Form value 2
```

I would like the form results to display 2 form labels and values per line.

Is it possible to change the formatting like this? What do I need to modify to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the "form_entry_add_body.soy" template file inside the web form portlet, but since it's not jsp we can not create a fragment file to override this soy file.

However you can create your own custom DDLFormEmailNotificationSender class and register with high service ranking and use modified template from there. There is a challenges to register this class because it's private class so you need to follow this [blog](https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/fixing-module-package-access-modifiers).

I tried to solve this way but i could not, have a look at this [liferay forum post](https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/104934134?_com_liferay_message_boards_web_portlet_MBPortlet_showBreadcrumb=false) so i have used dirty hack.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: So I'm not using a portlet I'm using Liferay 7 out of the box form wysiwyg.

Comment: Yes, it's Liferay OOTB functionality, but if you want to change the formatting you need to override "form_entry_add_body.soy" template through approach mentioned in the above answer.